# Python dict comprehension summing from objects

Tags: python

Given a setup like this:

```
class Foo():
   state = 'x'
   amount = 1


a = Foo()
b = Foo()
c = Foo()
c.state = 'y'
foos = [a, b, c]
```

I want to get a dict that has keys = `object.state`, values = `sum(object.amounts of objects with that state)`. In this case:

```
{'x': 2, 'y': 1}
```

I want to do this automatically, so I don't need to know the different possible states in advance.

For sure I could iterate through in some boring manner like this:

```
my_dict = {}
for foo in foos:
    try:
        my_dict[foo.state] += foo.value
    except (KeyError, TypeError):
        my_dict[foo.state] = foo.value
```

But that is a bit verbose, and I'm wondering if there's a nicer way to do it, maybe with dict comprehensions or something, but my efforts so far have been in vain.

Comment: Where is `foo.type` coming from?

Comment: Oops, sorry, fixed it, was from an old version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>>
>>> foos = [a,b,c]
>>> 
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for x in foos:
        c[x.state] += x.amount


>>> c
Counter({'x': 2, 'y': 1})
```

Comment: @Kasramvd .. my bad .. I was working with `itertools` at the same time on another question..:P

Comment: For completness, it's possible to do `Counter(f.state for f in foos for x in range(f.amount))`, but I don't feel it's good enough to get a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary comprehension is not the most optimized approach in this case. Instead you can use [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) like following :

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> 
>>> for obj in foos:
...     d[obj.state] += obj.amount
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'y': 1, 'x': 2})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use defaultdict.

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for foo in foos:
    my_dict[foo.type] += foo.value
```

You could also use setdefault.

```
my_dict = {}
for foo in foos:
    my_dict.setdefault(foo.type, 0)
    my_dict[foo.type] += foo.value
```